# Setting a property of a style's ControlTemplate in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

I want to access a property nested inside a style's control template. I know that you can do this in the code-behind:

```
GradientStop stop = (GradientStop)progressBar1.Template.FindName("gradStop", progressBar1);
stop.Color = Colors.Black;
```

Is it possible to do the same, but in the XAML? For example:

```
<ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" [???].Color="FF000000"/>
```

Comment: As far as I know you should use dynamic resources.

Comment: DynamicResource is probably the answer, yeah, if the ControlTemplate is built right. But if you're using a custom template, why are you even trying to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not use TemplateBinding?

```
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then specify the template bound values when you apply the style.